# Centering a widget inside another widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to center a QWidget localized inside a QTabWidget. When one resizes the inner QWidget I want it to be placed in the center always.

How can I do this?

Comment: Add spacers on all four sides around it in the layout

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus there are no layouts that support such combination. It is enough to add 2 spacers and set widget size policy of rest dimension to maximum. Or combine vertical + horizontal layout with 4 spaces, as you suggested :)

Comment: @SaZ There is a grid layout in Qt, which provide that feature.

Comment: Are you creating the widget from code or from Qt designer?

Comment: I have solved this problem by using layout alignment. Now my widget is aligned but resizing is working no more. It has a fixed size of minimum size which I have defined as 600X600. How can I enable risizing again?

Comment: Set an appropriate size policy, then. Most likely you want `MinimumExpanding` in both directions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1/ Create a layout in your `QTabWidget`: a `QBoxLayout` for example.

2/ Set your `QWidget` in it, with the desired alignment.

```
QTabWidget* tabwid = new QTabWidget(this);
QBoxLayout* layout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight, tabwid);
//if you want to set margins : layout->setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5); 
QWidget* widget = new QWidget();
layout->addWidget(widget, Qt::AlignCenter); // center alignment
```

Comment: The `addWidget()` syntax is not correct, since the second argument of [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) is the `stretch`, not the alignment. It should be `layout->addWidget(widget, 0, Qt::AlignCenter);`