# Centering Widget inside the main window

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'd like to center the `QTableWidget` widget inside the main window. Here is the code:

```
...
QApplication app(__argc, __argv);
MainWindow MainWnd;
MainWnd.setFixedSize(500, 500);

QTableWidget* table1 = new QTableWidget(3, 3);

// Set layout
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(table1, Qt::AlignCenter);

// Set layout in QWidget
QWidget* window = new QWidget();
window->setLayout(layout);

// Set QWidget as the central layout of the main window
MainWnd.setCentralWidget(window);

MainWnd.show();
return app.exec();
...
```

I've tried based on the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837731/centering-a-widget-inside-another-widget-in-qt). Unfortunately this DOESN'T work! the table isn't centered as on the image attached:

[image]

What's wrong with the code an how to fix it to work as expected?

Thx.